# How to get rid of the first comma in Python

Tags: python, django

```
        tags = ProductInStore.objects.get(id=product_in_store_id).product.tags.values_list('name', flat=True)
        converted_list = list(tags)
        tags_string = ''
        for tags in converted_list:
            tags_string += ',' + tags
        return tags_string
```

The output is

```
,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5
```

but i'd like to get rid of the first comma. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `str.join(iterable)` method instead of the for loop:

```py
tag_string = ",".join(tags)
```

Comment: I.e., the best way to get rid of the first comma is to not put it there in the first place :)

Comment: This is also much more efficient than repeatedly creating temporary `str` objects; the loop takes O(n^2) time, as opposed to O(n) for `','.join`.

Comment: Since this is tagged Django, then there's also a join filter. In a template, `{{taglist|join:", "}}`

Answer (score 1):

`return tags_string.lstrip(",")`

Answer (score 0):

```
return tags_string.strip(",")
```

Note: it will also remove "," (if any) from the end of string.

Answer (score -1):

You will have three approaches in front of you:

###### Option 1: Using for loop and `enumerate`

```py
tags_string = ""
length = len(converted_list)
for index ,tags in enumerate(converted_list):
  if index != length:
    tags_string +=  tags + ","
  else:
    tags_string +=  tags
tags_string
```

###### Option 2: Using `lstrip`

```py
for tags in converted_list:
    tags_string += ',' + tags
tags_string.lstrip(",")
```

###### Option 3: Using `join`

```py
",".join(converted_list)
```

All three approaches would result in the same output:

```
tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5
```